How to translate "Showing all XX results" or "Showing X–XX of XX results" in the Flatsome theme in WordPress into another language?
I have tried many ways and asked several AIs but have not found a solution yet. Can anyone help me? Thank you!
image 1  image 2 
I have tried several plugins, but they only translate some of the words on the site, while others do not work.
I have spent quite a lot of time trying to resolve this issue, but it has not been effective.

The javascript for it is relatively simple. Just get the current text and .replace("Showing", "other language")

You can achieve your desired result with the help of gettext filter of WordPress, with the help of that you can translate the string.
add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_english_text', 10, 3 );
 
function translate_english_text($translated, $text, $domain) {
    // Your custom translations can be compared and changed here.
    if ( $text === 'Your original string' ) { // Here you need to replace 'Your original string' with the string you wantto replace.
        return 'Your translated string'; // The string you want to show in place of 'Your original string'.
    }

    // You can also add more conditions for translations as per your need.

    return $translated;
}

Note: You need to find the string you want to replace in your codebase so you can applied the accurate condition.
Please let me know if this helps.
